# R filtering on deep structured lists: Any better idioms?

Tags: r

When handling structured data I often end up writing expressions like this in R:

```
big_container_list$internal_data_frame[big_container_list$internal_data_frame$person_name=="Max Planck",]
```

Is there a way to make this unweildy? Either by using a better idiom or by fundamentally redefining the way I am creating my data structures.

It gets worse if the internal filtering condition has an AND / OR etc. or the data structure nesting level is deeper.

Comment: I'm not clear on the question, are you looking for cleaner ways to reach inside the data structure?

Comment: @lmo Yes. In a large nested list if I want to filter objects nested at internal nested levels of the list the current idiom I'm using seems very unwieldy.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of the data, or a similar structure? Maybe `dput` the head of the list?